# Defining a bag Multiset with elements and multiplicity pairs In Ada

Tags: ada, type-declaration

I have to meet a specification which says that I have to write a bag type which is a record with discriminant , which is the maximum capacity of the bag in the record I have to put an array that contains element and multiplicity pairs , I have written some code and updated it as well

```ada
type TArray is array (Integer range <>) of Elem,Multi;
type Bag (Max : Positive) is record
                                Data    : TArray (1 .. Max);
                                Pointer : Natural := 0;
                             end record;
```

The code has been updated please check and suggest

Comment: I've edited your question, so the source text is syntax high-lighted.  You may want to take a look at how I did it.  (Easier than looking up the manual. ;-)

Comment: Your array type looks incomplete, if it both should contain both elements and multiplicities.

Comment: If you’re going to post code you should really try compiling it! You need an array of a record type, where the record type contains an element and a multiplicity

Comment: I beg your pardon, but where is the question / compilation error / execution exception ?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is quite simple : if you don't have any error messages at compilation phase, it's ok.

Well according to what you described, your code looks good. I have a question about it.

Do you plan to have negative indexes on your type TArray ? If not, why don't you use the same type as your discriminant ?

The only thing is that you'll have only half the values using Positive instead of Integer but in your record, you anyway already start at 1 and thus have the same range as Positive.

Comment: Just compiling successfully doesn’t indicate correctness!

Comment: Of course not but regarding the information contained in the question, it's a first step :)